# how to set u a react/node project with babel and webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

i'm tryng to setup a new react project with babel and webpack but it's not working. this is my webpack.dev.config.js file :

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var parentDir = path.join(__dirname, '../');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        path.join(parentDir, '/react_components/index.js')
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                  }
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: parentDir + '/html',
        filename: 'main.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: parentDir,
        historyApiFallback: true
    }
}
```

and this is a screen shot from my project :

[image]

i get the message that webpack is compiled successfully but the main.js file remain empty

PS : i'm using this tutorial

https://medium.com/netscape/setting-up-a-react-project-from-scratch-d62f38ab6d97

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `node node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js` in project directory and it should build a phyisical main.js file.

> The webpack-dev-server doesn't write to disk. It serves the result
>   from memory.

Source: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/24

Answer (score 0):

Open package.json file. Inside scripts add `"build": "webpack"`

Your scripts object should essentially look something like this  :

`"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot",
    "build":"webpack"
  }`

then run `npm run build` on your terminal.

Comment: Agreed. There will be a two step process. Bundle with webpack first, then start the server in a separate terminal.

Comment: As @RudolphTheCat said, webpack-dev-server doesn't write to disk, instead serves from memory. So when you're running webpack-dev-server, the main.js will not get updated, since it is not required. For production purpose only you need main.js.

Comment: If you simply want to see the main.js file you can in the chrome dev tools.